# Sort and group multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array eg:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => best_of_web
            [id] => 1136
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => org_content
            [id] => 1139
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => org_content
            [id] => 1141
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => best_of_web
            [id] => 1143
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => org_content
            [id] => 1144
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [quick_filter] => best_of_web
            [id] => 1145
        )

)
```

and I want to sort it in such order

```
Array
(
    [best_of_web]
    Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1136
                [1] => 1143
                [2] => 1145
            )
    )

    [org_content]
    Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1139
                [1] => 1141
                [2] => 1144
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you having a particular problem doing so? Do you know how to iterate over an array? How to access array elements?

Comment: And where are you going wrong in your attempts to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$output_array = array();
foreach ($input_array as $item) {
    if (!isset($output_array[$item['quick_filter']]['id'])) {
        $output_array[$item['quick_filter']]['id'] = array();
    }
    $output_array[$item['quick_filter']]['id'][] = $item['id'];
}
```

Replace `$input_array` with the array you want sorted.

Answer (score 1):

How about..

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach ($sourceArray as $key=>$value){

   if (!isset($resultArray[$value['quick_filter']]))

      /* set a new key to $resultArray */
      $resultArray[$value['quick_filter']]['id'] = array($value['id']);

   } else {

      /* add id to $resultArray*/
      $resultArray[$value['quick_filter']]['id'][] = $value['id'];

   }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `id` key in the requested data structure.

Comment: Thanks! Will update shortly (didn't make sense having id key in the array though)

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($array as $index) $merged[$index['quick_filter']]['id'][] = $index['id'];
print_r($merged);
```